# What is the best way to reassign ordinal number of a move operation

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a column in the sql server called "Ordinal" that is used to indicate the display order of the rows.  It starts from 0 and skips 10 for the next row.  so we have something like this:

```
Id  Ordinal
1    0
2    20
3    10
```

It skips 10 because we wanted to be able to move item in between items (based on ordinal) without having to reassign ordinal number for the entire table.

As you can imagine eventually, Ordinal number will need to be reassign somehow for a move in between operation either on surrounding rows or for the entire table as the unused ordinal numbers between the target items are all used up.

Is there any algorithm that I can use to effectively reorder the ordinal number for the move operation taken in the consideration like long term maintainability of the table and minimizing update operations of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-number the sequences using a somewhat complicated `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.sequence = 10 * (c.num_below-1)
FROM test u
JOIN (
  SELECT t.id, count(*) AS num_below
  FROM test t
  JOIN test tr ON tr.sequence <= t.sequence
  GROUP BY t.id
) c ON c.id=u.id
```

The idea is to obtain a count of items with the `sequence` *lower* than that of the current row, multiply the count by ten, and assign it as the new count.

The content of `test` before the `UPDATE`:

```
ID  Sequence
__  ________
 1   0
 2  10
 3  20
 4  12
```

The content of `test` after the `UPDATE`:

```
ID  Sequence
__  ________
 1   0
 2  30
 3  10
 4  20
```

Now the sequence numbers are evenly spread again, so you can continue inserting in the middle until you run out of new sequence numbers; then you can re-number again.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00da/1)

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  Your approach will probably require the least amount of reordering for the lifetime of the entire application as it spreads out all the rows evenly again.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These won't answer your question directly--I just thought I might suggest some other approaches:

One possibility--don't try to do it by hand.  Have your software manage the numbers.  If they need re-writing, just save them with new numbers.

a second--use a "Linked List" instead.  In each record store the index of the next record you want displayed, then have your code load that directly into a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another simple approach. Let's say you're inserting a new record with an `ordinal` equal `x`.

First, check if there's a row having `ordinal` value equal `x`. In case there's one, just update all the records having the `ordinal` value equal or bigger than `x` increasing them by `y`. Then, you are safe to insert a new record.

This way you're sure you'll not run `update` every time and of course, you'll keep the order.